# Java containsKey() on ConcurrentHashMap returns false for a UUID key that present in the map

Tags: java, uuid, concurrenthashmap

I am using an object of type

```
Map<Long, Map<UUID, OperationEntry>> stepOperations = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

to control the execution of some operations. I have a Kafka message handler method that, upon receiving a message about a status change of an operation, needs to find and update the state of a record in stepOperations map based on the passed UUID.

UUID class is not overriden (standatd java.util.UUID).

What could be the reason for getting an unexpected result from the containsKey method if the key "3102869c-7653-4fb7-ad47-a629b5cbac90", as clearly seen in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0PkX.png), is present in the map?

Here is the problematic part of the code:

```
   private OperationEntry getOperationLogEntry(UUID requestId) {
        return stepOperations.values().stream()
            .filter(value -> value.containsKey(requestId))
            .map(value -> value.get(requestId))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
    }
```

The ConcurrentHashMap class is used due to its guaranted support for multithreaded processing. The incoming Kafka messages are processed by a thread pool consisting of 16 threads.

Could the presence of a inner map be a potential issue here?

Simple test such as

```
        Map<UUID, String> testMap = new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        UUID key = UUID.randomUUID();
        testMap.put(key, "testValue");
        if (testMap.containsKey(key)) {
            System.out.println(testMap.get(key));
        }
```

works as it's expected to be

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please include your code as text as well. By the way, how do you know it's not working? What are you checking to determine it's not working? What result do you expect and what are you getting instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the debugger, we can see that `value` variable in an `HashMap`. Not a `ConcurrentHashMap`:

[image: HashMap]

When you work with multi levels of map, you should use `computeIfAbsent`.

From your code, you should probably:

- have `stepOperations` be `ConcurrentMap<Long, ConcurrentMap<UUID, Whatever>>` to make sure the two levels are good.
- use `computeIfAbsent` as in `stepOperations.computeIfAbsent(key, ignored -> new ConcurrentHashMap<>())`
- ensure that the map itself is not accessible externally (where the map could be polluted).

To add a new step:

```
stepOperations.computeIfAbsent(opId,  ignored -> new ConcurrentHashMap<>()))
              .put(opUUID, opWhatever)
```

Finally, you could probably rewrite your code:

```
stepOperations
   .values()
   .stream()
   .filter(value -> value.containsKey(operationRunState.requestId))
   .map(value -> value.get(operationRunState.requestId))
   .findFirst()
```

Do that instead:

```
var id = operationRunState.requestId;
stepOperations
   .values()
   .stream().map(value -> value.get(id))
   .filter(Objects::nonNull)
   .findFirst();
```

Two points:

- use a local variable `id` to ensure you use the same id
- `ConcurrentHashMap` forbids key and value from being `null`: the `containsKey` is useless here.

Comment: I was halfway through writing a similar answer :) - @itnick - the _outer_ map is a `ConcurrentHashMap`, but it consists of k/v mappings where each value is a plain jane `HashMap`. An outer ConcurrentHashMap is not some magic spell that fixes all concurrency problems. The inner stuff also needs to be concurrency-capable, _and_ you still can't just go: Oh, I used CHM, so I'm fine. You need to use concurrency-capable primitives, and use them correctly. Even CHM can't magically fix `if (!map.containsKey(k)) map.put(k, v);` - that is broken. On everything. `putIfAbsent` works for CHMs concurrently.

Comment: thank you for your responses. Indeed, replacing
```
private final Map<Long, Map<UUID, OperationEntry>> stepOperations = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
``` with

``` private final ConcurrentMap<Long, ConcurrentMap<UUID, OperationEntry>> stepOperations = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); ```
had helped. In this case, the inner map is also must be concurrent.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your responses. Indeed, replacing

```
private final Map<Long, Map<UUID, OperationEntry>> stepOperations = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

with

```
private final ConcurrentMap<Long, ConcurrentMap<UUID, OperationEntry>> stepOperations = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

had helped. In this case, the inner map is also must be concurrent.

Comment: I’m glad you found a solution. If you found the other answer helpful, you should accept it and vote it up, rather than writing your own answer.

Comment: Sorry that you think that’s what happened here. I was trying to offer guidance on how this site works. At the time I wrote the comment, the other answer had not been accepted.

Comment: Thank you for your advices, really. Anyway it was a new expireince, and it shouldn't be easy :)"